Why socket io is not working on my client side?
I intend to create rooms on a server that lets groups of two users communicate or send messages to each other. I have used the following code to start the server and point the default file to the appropriate HTML file. On the event of opening the port the server on a browser, I do not get the message connected on the console despite the code existing in my file. Here is how server.js looks like
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const socketIo = require('socket.io');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo(server);

// Serve static files from the "public" directory
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Handle the root route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    //load the page for the first player
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'playerA.html'));
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('a user connected');

    socket.on('joinRoom', (room) => {
        socket.join(room);
        console.log(`User joined room: ${room}`);
    });

    socket.on('move', (data) => {
        const { room, message } = data;
        io.to(room).emit('move', message);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

I have added the reference to the socket.io.js to my client file as show below
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!--add bootstrap to the file-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <!--importing the socket io file on my client side-->
    
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <!--draw the checkerboard for player A here-->
    <!--point this page to its own javascript file-->
    <h3 class="heading">DRAFT PESA</h3>

    <h5 class="player_name">Player A  Name</h5>
    <div class="container mystyle">
        <div>
            <h5 class="messages" id="playerA"></h5>
        </div>
        <center><table id="checkertable"></table></center>
        <div>
            <h5 class="messages" id="playerB"></h5>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h5 class="player_name">Player B  Name</h5>
    <!--add a reference to socket.io.js-->
    <script src="socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="playerA.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

I then try to use the socket io from my code like below
  let message = "player A has moved from " + x1 + ":" + y1 + " to " + row + ":" + col;
  //send the message to another user viewing the same page on a different device but on the same server
  const sock = new io();
  const room = 'room1';  // This can be dynamically set based on your application logic
  sock.emit('joinRoom', room);
  socket.emit('move', { room, message });

  sock.on('move', (msg) => {
      console.log(msg);
  });
  console.log(message);

I get the following error in my HTML file
ReferenceError: io is not defined
    at HTMLTableCellElement.<anonymous>

How do I solve this? I expected that on moving a piece then I can see the message that I sent from the client get printed on the server terminal. This is the only message that gets printed on the screen, the message in the listen on port code.


Try to change the reference to your socket.io.js  from this code
<!--add a reference to socket.io.js-->
<script src="socket.io.js"></script>

to this one
<!--add a reference to socket.io.js-->
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

the code above works fine for me in one my web app
